# file_get_contents doesn't get the content of the correct file

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

I'm trying to build a script that will show a new IP based on the state name. The IP's should be taken from a file with the same name as the state name. Then it takes a random IP and assigns it (this is how it should work).

The problem is that it assigns totally random IP's and loads them IP's from a random file instead of taking it from the correct file with the state name.

How this should work: california > california.txt > random IP

How this works now: california > newyork/georgia/texas/etc.txt > random IP

```
$state_content=["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado","Connecticut","Delaware","Florida","Georgia","Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois","Indiana","Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana","Nebraska","Nevada","NewHampshire","NewJersey","NewMexico","NewYork","NorthCarolina","NorthDakota","Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvania","RhodeIsland","SouthCarolina","SouthDakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah","Vermont","Virginia","Washington","WestVirginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"];

$country_content=["UnitedStates", "UnitedKingdom", "Canada", "Australia", "Germany", "France", "Spain"];

$a = 0;

function getStateContent($state_name) {

    // checks do we already have content for this state
    if(!isset($state_content[$state_name])) {

        // generate file name
        $file_name = "state/";
        $file_name .= str_replace(" ", "", ucwords($state_name));
        $file_name .= ".txt";

        $state_text = file_get_contents($file_name);
        $state_content[$state_name] = explode("\n", $state_text);
    }

    return $state_content[$state_name];
}

function getStateIpByName($state_name) {
    $content = getStateContent($state_name);
    return $content[array_rand($content)];
}

function getCountryContent($country_name) {

    // checks do we already have content for this state
    if(!isset($country_content[$country_name])) {

        // generate file name
        $file_name = "country/";
        $file_name .= str_replace(" ", "", ucwords($country_name));
        $file_name .= ".txt";

        $country_text = file_get_contents($file_name);
        $country_content[$country_name] = explode("\n", $country_text);
    }

    return $country_content[$country_name];
}

function getCountryIpByName($country_name) {
    $content = getCountryContent($country_name);
    return $content[array_rand($content)];
}
```

Usage:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo "<div class='block'><div class='rows'>";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        if (!empty($row["state"]) && $row["country"] == "united states") {
            $stateip = getStateIpByName($row["state"]);
            $a++;
            echo $stateip;
        }

        else if (empty($row["state"]) && $row["country"] == "united states") {
            $countryip = getCountryIpByName($row["country"]);
            $a++;
            echo $countryip;
          }

        else if ($row["country"] != "united states") {

        }

    }
```

Comment: See these statements, `$state_content[$state_name] = explode("\n", $state_text);` and `$country_content[$country_name] = explode("\n", $country_text);`. The original arrays i.e. `$state_content` and `$country_content` are getting manipulated/changed every time the corresponding functions get called from the `while` loop.

Comment: I see. Any Ideas on how can I fix this?

Comment: What do these files contain? IP addresses? Also, what are are trying to do with *those* statements?

Comment: Those files contain IP's like 1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2 (1 per line). I'm trying to output the newly generate data onto the page.

Comment: I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment,

These statements `$state_content[$state_name] = explode("\n", $state_text);` and `$country_content[$country_name] = explode("\n", $country_text);` manipulates/changes the original array every time the corresponding functions get called from the `while()` loop.

**The solution** is, (After discussing on chat)

Change `getStateContent()` and `getCountryContent()` functions in the following way,

```
function getStateContent($state_name) {
    // checks do we already have content for this state
    global $state_content;
    $state_name = str_replace(" ", "", ucwords($state_name));
    if(in_array($state_name, $state_content)) {
        // generate file name
        $file_name = "state/";
        $file_name .= $state_name;
        $file_name .= ".txt";

        $state_text = file_get_contents($file_name);
        $ipaddresses = explode("\n", $state_text);
        return $ipaddresses;
    }
}
```

and

```
function getCountryContent($country_name) {
    // checks do we already have content for this state
    global $country_content;
    $country_name = str_replace(" ", "", ucwords($country_name));
    if(in_array($country_name, $country_content)) {
        // generate file name
        $file_name = "country/";
        $file_name .= $country_name;
        $file_name .= ".txt";

        $country_text = file_get_contents($file_name);
        $ipaddresses = explode("\n", $country_text);
        return $ipaddresses;

    }
}
```

Comment: It just shows a blank page with `state/California.txt`... I need to see all the records with newly assigned IP's on the page and this is why I used `while`. Something here is horribly wrong. Maybe you forgot about the `getStateIpByName($state_name)` function that retrieves a random IP from the associated file? Or maybe I just don't get how should I apply this into the `while` loop?

Comment: @Ricardo Oh, my bad. I accidentally kept `die($file_name);` in that function, that's why. I used that to debug your issue. I've updated my answer. And you don't need to change any `while` loop, you just need to modify those functions, that's it.

Comment: What should I write in the `while` loop then instead of `echo $stateip;`?
I think you didn't understand fully understand the question.
I take data from my database and need to assign EACH ROW with a NEW IP from a text file. I assume that what you did is just showing the contents of a specific .txt file. Where is the Assignment of the new IP per every database row?

Comment: Please look in question post: `How this should work: california > california.txt > random IP`. Basically every time `california` will show up it will be replaced with a random IP from `california.txt`. So for every California field in the table we get (shown up on the page) a random californian IP.

Comment: @Ricardo Okay, so with these `$stateip` and `$countryip` you get a random ip address from the file(based on the state or country in each iteration of `while` loop). So what are you trying to do with this random ip address?

Comment: Correct. I'm trying to `echo` it on the page. So ill see an `id`:`randomNewIP` for each row :)

Comment: @Ricardo You mean this, `echo 'id : ' . $stateip;` or `echo 'id : ' . $countryip;`?

Comment: The 2nd option. It'll be more like: `echo $row["id"]. ":" . $stateip;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125385/discussion-between-rajdeep-paul-and-ricardo).